# Please help a noob out with installing Ubuntu

Tags: installation, boot, live-usb

So I am brand new to Linux. I have an older laptop that is collecting dust and am trying to install Ubuntu 12.04.3 onto it. It's a Dell Studio 1735 running Vista 64bit that I bought back in 08.

I have the iso on a usb drive, done with "UNetbootin". I formatted the drive to FAT32 before loading anything onto it.

From what I understand, I get to the boot menu, go to "boot from usb", and select "install ubuntu" from the UNetbootin menu. I get the menu, but if I click on any option in there (All option are listed twice for some reason) the Ubuntu screen (purple screen with red dots underneath "Ubuntu") will come up for about a minute or so, then it will bring me back to the UNetbootin screen. But the menu will be shrunken up and up in the corner, and underneath it will be some text.

"BusyBox v1.18.5 (Ubuntu 1:1.18.5-1ubuntu4.1) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs) _"

I can input commands here, and the help menu will come up but I do not know what I'm doing. And from what I understand I shouldn't need to do any command prompt stuff to just get it to install. I took a video in case I'm not explaining this well enough: [Link Here](http://youtu.be/ux53Du48Mjo)

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download Ubuntu 13.10 64 bit version:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?release=latest&bits=64&distro=desktop&status=zeroc

Use Universal USB installer to create the pendrive:

http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/

Use the following guide to install:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-latest

Comment: There is 4GB of ram, so 64 should be okay from what I've read. Downloading the version you linked now, thank you for answering, will post my results.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, please report the succesful installation.

Comment: It seems to be working. Thank you so much, I really do appreciate it